# Delete words with specific string in a text document in Notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++

I have a file with contents like

```
00001 abcd
00020 abcdefgh
0030 acgefty
00040 jhjhjdsadj2
00050 sadjjjah589
00500 blessing
```

I need to delete all numbers at beginning, i.e., I need a result file

```
abcd
abcdefgh
acgefty
jhjhjdsadj2
sadjjjah589
blessing
```

Can someone help, as the actual file is approx 600 lines long, so difficult to delete the numbers at start manually. I don't mind running a small C program.

Comment: Did you consider writing yourself that small C program?

Comment: the notepad++ solution: Ctrl+H, enable RegEx-Search, write a short RegEx for the numbers and leave the "replace-with"-field empty. Then press "replace all"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `^\d+\s*`
Replace with: `NOTHING`